# I found the source of my lagging GUI, a function, but what can I do?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've found the cause of my lagging GUI, it's the function `inRegularIntervals()`

It takes an array of numbers and sort them like this:

```
{0: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 10: [10, 18], 20: [28], 30: [], 40: [], 50: [], 60: [], 70: [70, 73, 73, 75], 80: [80], 90: [], 100: [106], 110: [], 120: [], 130: [], 140: [140], 150: [150], 160: [], 170: [170], 180: [], 190: [194, 196], 200: [200, 202], 210: [], 220: [], 230: [], 240: [], 250: [], 260: [], 270: [], 280: [], 290: [], 300: [], 310: [], 320: [], 330: [336], 340: [], 350: [353, 356].............................................}
```

After that I count the items for each bin

```
def inRegularIntervals(data, interval):
     """Sorts elements of data into bins of regular sizes.
     The size of each bin is given by 'interval'."""
     # init dict so keys are ordered - collection.defaultdict(list) 
     # would be faster - but this works for lists of a couple of
     # thousand numbers if you have a quarter up to one second ...

     # if random key order is ok, shorten this to d = {} 
        
     d = {k:[] for k in range(0, max(data), interval)}  
     for n in data:
        key = n // interval # get key
        key *= interval
        d.setdefault(key, [])
        d[key].append(n) # add number
        
     return d

#First I put values into the array transactions_NOT_sorted#
transactions_NOT_sorted.append(int(round(amount))) 


#Then I sort the values into bins of regular sizes. transaction_sorted is a list#
transactions_sorted = inRegularIntervals(transactions_NOT_sorted,10)

#count items for each bin 
for key, value in transactions_sorted.items():         
        count_items = len([item for item in value if item])
               if count_items > 0:
                    data_for_plot[key]=count_items
```

I need a faster version of this. Should I use threading or multiprocessing?

Comment: 1) Why do you create empty bins in the first place if you're not using them? 2) why ``count_items = len([item for item in value if item])`` and not just ``count_items = len(value)`` or more simplistic ``if value:``? 3) if you have working code, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @MikeScotty For your 2nd point, shouldn't you use `filter` with `bool` because of the `if item` part? That `if` statement is applied to all of the elements.

Comment: @TheLizzard ``item`` can only be falsy if it's zero, which can only be the case for the ``0`` bin, so it should probably be optimized while creating bins to not needlessly check this for all other bins. But this might also depend on the use case (if ``data_for_plot`` is using 0 values at all).

Comment: @MikeScotty, When you suggest code review, please direct the user to our help page at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good reference is https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778